# Android null pointer method before startup

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

For my project I have a method that should update the city after changing it in the settings tab. What I did was create a method, changeCity(string city) but when I start the application changeCity is always null, I tried putting the method on other places, but then my app keeps crashing. Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks,
    WeatherFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);



}


 @Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new RecipeListFragment();

            break;
        case 1:

            fragment = new WeatherFragment();

            //SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            //String weatherLocation = SP.getString("weatherLocation", "NA");

            //changeCity(weatherLocation + ", NL");
            //changeCity("Breda, NL");

            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new SettingsFragment();
           // changeCity("Terneuzen, NL");
            break;
    }

    fragmentManager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item selected -> " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void changeCity(String city){
    WeatherFragment wf = (WeatherFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    wf.changeCity(city);
    new CityPreference(this).setCity(city);
}
```

Here's the stacktrace when i put the method in the switch case 2:

```
06-23 15:52:44.413  21422-21422/nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1, PID: 21422
java.lang.ClassCastException: nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1.RecipeListFragment cannot be cast to nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1.WeatherFragment
        at nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1.MainActivity.changeCity(MainActivity.java:81)
        at nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1.MainActivity.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(MainActivity.java:72)
        at nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:174)
        at nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1.NavigationDrawerFragment.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:104)
        at nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1.NavigationDrawerAdapter$1.onClick(NavigationDrawerAdapter.java:47)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Here's the stacktrace when I use the method in the oncreate:

```
06-23 15:54:02.597  23278-23278/nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1, PID: 23278
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1/nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1.WeatherFragment.changeCity(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1.WeatherFragment.changeCity(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1.MainActivity.changeCity(MainActivity.java:82)
        at nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
```

After trying the answer:

```
06-23 16:24:17.913  23712-23712/nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1, PID: 23712
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.app.Activity.getString(int)' on a null object reference
        at nl.shacklez.mijnreceptenofficialv1.WeatherFragment$1$1.run(WeatherFragment.java:111)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Where is the stacktrace??

Comment: please post you error log

Comment: Sorry, added the log

Answer (score 0):

findFragmentById(R.id.container) returned a RecipeListFragment.
Your program tried to cast RecipeListFragment to WeatherFragment.

Comment: Ye I know, but the code works fine without the changecity method, all problems start when I use that method. I have no idea where to run it from, and get no errors. Why can't I just run the method :(...

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace shows that you are trying to cast `RecipeListFragment` to `WeatherFragment`. Source of that error is in your `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected` code where you are first calling `changeCity` and then changing fragment with `fragmentManager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();`

Simplest way to resolve this situation would be to pass fragment to your `changeCity` method instead of searching for it.

```
public void changeCity(WeatherFragment wf, String city){
    wf.changeCity(city);
    new CityPreference(this).setCity(city);
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
fragment = new WeatherFragment();
changeCity((WeatherFragment) fragment, "Breda, NL");
```

Comment: It is impossible to tell without rest of your code. Maybe you can solve that by `create fragment -> replace fragment -> changeCity` sequence, but I am just wild guessing. You will have to learn how to untangle your code yourself. Read stack trace and it will tell you where your errors are. Then adjust code logic to get around them.